# R1Soft CDP2 disk safe - make previous disk safe be active

Tags: linux, backup, cdp, r1soft

Hoping that someone will be able to dust off some ancient R1Soft CDP2 knowledge on this =).

How can you make a previous disk safe active so that backups can be made to it again?  For example, if a new disk safe was created, then deleted, how can the previous disk safe be marked active again.  I don't think there's any way to do this in the interface, but I wonder if there's some way to do it by editing some file manually.

[image]

Long story short, I need to do this to be able to correct the partition table on that disk safe to be able to render its recovery points usable again.

Comment: Why are you still using CDP2, it is many years old...

Comment: @FlorinAsăvoaie Almost transitioned off of it.  CDP5 causes the agent machine we're using CDP2 on to crash the filesystems into read-only mode and require a reboot and repair, so we're coinciding transitioning off of it with moving off that server (which is running CentOS 5).  Would be nice to figure this out though to try to be able to access the recovery points we had.